# Angular or JS Dynamic Variable Pointer Name

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to do the below.  I think this might not be possible, but if so please share.  I am trying to just change the this.c# based on a if statement vs. writing the data.filter over and over 3 times.

```
if (chart === 'c1') {
        currentChart = this.c1;
      } else if (chart === 'c2') {
        currentChart = this.c2;
      } else if (chart === 'c3') {
        currentChart = this.c3;
      }
      currentChart = data.filter(o => {
```

Something like that.
The issue being not reassigning the pointer to data.filter. But inserting this.c# = data.filter, which points to this.c#

Comment: Are you wanting linq like functions in Javascript?

Comment: @Ohjay44 the # in c# in his question means "number", but I was confused as well first ;-)

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe thanks for clarifying, I was a bit confused. However, not that it pertains to this question, you can use linq with a library in JS which is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (chart === 'c1') {
    currentChart = this.c1;
  } else if (chart === 'c2') {
    currentChart = this.c2;
  } else if (chart === 'c3') {
    currentChart = this.c3;
  }
```

could be replaced by

```
currentChart = this[chart];
```

or, more safe :

```
currentChart = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'].includes(chart) ? this[chart] : null;
```